# How do I write my own `reduce` function?

Tags: javascript

I want write `reduce` by myself. But over the last 4 hours, I couldn't.

```
var a = [10, 21, 13, 56];

function add(a, b) { return a + b }
function foo(a, b) { return a.concat(b) }

Array.prototype.reduce2 = function () {
  // I do not understand how to handle the function of the inlet
  // I know that I should use arguments, but I don't know how many arguments there will be
  var result = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    result += arguments[i];
  }
 return result;
};

console.log(a.reduce(add), a.reduce2(add))         // 100 100
console.log(a.reduce(add, 10), a.reduce2(add, 10)) // 110 110
```

Yes, I know that this seems like a lot of topics, but I couldn't find answer.  What am I missing, or doing wrong here?

Comment: You don't need to use `arguments` - declare them explicitly as `function(reducer, initialValue)`

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Polyfill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill)? That should give you some hints

Answer (score 7):

The array in subject is not passed as argument, but is the context (`this`).

You also need to distinguish between the presence or absence of the start value:

```js
var a = [10, 21, 13, 56];

function add(a, b) { return a + b }
function foo(a, b) { return a.concat(b) }

Array.prototype.reduce2 = function (f, result) {
  var i = 0;
  if (arguments.length < 2) {
    i = 1;
    result = this[0];
  }
  for(; i < this.length; i++) {
    result = f(result, this[i], i, this);
  }
  return result;
};
console.log(a.reduce(add), a.reduce2(add))         // 100 100
console.log(a.reduce(add, 10), a.reduce2(add, 10)) // 110 110
// extra test with foo:
console.log(a.reduce(foo, 'X'), a.reduce2(foo, 'X')) // X10211356 X10211356
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code

```js
var a = [10, 21, 13, 56];

function add(a, b) { return a + b }
function foo(a, b) { return a.concat(b) }

Array.prototype.reduce2 = function(fn, start){
  var result = start !== undefined ? start : this[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    result = fn(result, this[i]);
  }
  return result;
};
console.log(a.reduce(add), a.reduce2(add))         // 100 100
console.log(a.reduce(add, 10), a.reduce2(add, 10)) // 110 110
console.log(a.reduce(foo, ''), a.reduce2(foo, ''));
console.log(a.reduce(foo, 'X'), a.reduce2(foo, 'X'));
```

Comment: No I didn't but now I do. Thanks, "> You also need to distinguish between the presence or absence of the start value" helps me to understand what i missed.

Comment: There are still issues. When you solve them your code will not be much different from my answer. For instance, try passing a non-empty string as start value for `foo`. ;-)

Comment: Argh, what a shame. I removed the useless part ( which added the additional argument... the default value -_- ). Thanks for your help (and now i hope that i didn't forget anything ^^)

Comment: Now check what remains different in your code from mine, and how that affects the result.... ;-)

Comment: @SergeyB, why would you want to use `slice`? That will only introduce incompatibilities with the standard `reduce`.

Comment: @ trincot I have a task, rewrite `reduce` with `slice` and `recursion`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that my answer is exactly answering the question, but I hope this may help someone.

Example without using prototype and loops:

```
const origArr = [2,2]
const origFunc = (p,c) => p+c
const initial = 1

const reduce = (func, array, initial) => {
  const rec = (arr, acc) => {
    // arr: [2, 2], [2], []
    // acc: 1, 3, 5
    if (!arr.length) return acc
    const curr = arr[0]
    const nextArr = arr.slice(1)
    const nextAcc = func(acc, curr)
    return rec(nextArr, nextAcc)
  }
  if (initial) {
    return rec(array, initial)
  }
  return rec(array.slice(1), array[0])
}

console.log(origArr.reduce(origFunc, initial)) // 5
console.log(reduce(origFunc, origArr, initial)) // 5
```

And example with loop:

```
const reduceLoop = (func, array, initial) => {
    let acc = initial !== undefined ? initial : array[0]
    let arr = initial !== undefined ? [initial, ...array] : array
    for(let i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {
      acc = func(acc, arr[i])
    }
    return acc
}
```

As you you can see, in first example we do not assigning variables, we just have some constants, but in the example with loop we assigning tha `acc` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Below code reduces the passed array to single value. Need to pass a function on what has to be done on the array and initial value if needed.

```
Array.prototype.myFunction = function(fn,initial) {
    let arayEl = this;
    console.log(arayEl);
    let total = initial || 0;
    for(let i=0;i<arayEl.length;i++) {
        total = fn(total,arayEl[i]);
    }
    return total;
}

console.log([1,2,3].myFunction(function(total,x){return total +x},10));
console.log([1,2,3].reduce(function(total,x){return total +x},10));
console.log([1,2,3].myFunction(function(total,x){return total * x},10));
console.log([1,2,3].reduce(function(total,x){return total * x},10));
```

- **myFunction** is custom reduce function which accepts a callback funtion(fn) and a initial value which is optional. It will work just like reducer.
- **callBack function** function(total,x){return total + x} is passed as param to myFunction which is then reduced to single value. Here instead of add, we can perform any operation same like reduce.

Comment: You can improve your answer by describing _how_ your code works, rather than just posting a block of code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const reduceV1 = (list, cb, intial) => {
  let memo = intial;
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0 && memo === undefined) {
      memo = list[0];
    } else {
      memo = cb(list[i], memo);
    }
  }

  return memo;
};

function sumV1(n, sum) {
  return n + sum;
}

console.log(reduceV1([1, 2], sumV1));
console.log(reduceV1([1, 2,3], sumV1,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actual reduce fuction:

```
const list = [1,2,3,4,5];
const sum = list => list.reduce((total, val)=> total+val, 0)
console.log(sum(list));
```

If we look closely then we need three things: a list to iterate over , initial value and a reduce function

```
const reduceHelper = (list, initialValue, reducer) => {
// If the list is empty we will just return initial value
  if(list.length === 0) {
    return initialValue;
  } else {
    const [first, ...rest] = list;
    const updatedAcc = reducer(initialValue, first);
    return reduceHelper(rest, updatedAcc, reducer);
  }
}
// test it 
const list = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log( myReduce(list, 0, (total, val) => total + val))
```

The idea is the same. We can follow the same idea and write different reduce function for counting words.......

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.myReduce = function(callback, initialValue) {
  var a = initialValue;
  for(let i=0; i<this.length;i++){
     callback(a=a+this[i]);
  }
  return a;
}
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
var result = arr.myReduce((next,prev) =>next+prev,10);
console.log(result);                    //25
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 Default Parameters:

```js
const nums = [1, 5, 5, 9];

Array.prototype.customReduce = function (callback, initial=0) {
  let result = initial;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    result = callback(result, this[i]);
  }
  return result;
};

const sum = nums.customReduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
console.log(sum); // 20
```

Comment: No, that's not how it works. If the `initial` argument is not provided, the loop should make one less iteration, and the initial value should be the value of the first array element. Note that reduce should work for other types than integers. Think of strings, objects, ...etc. So `0` is not desired as initial value in those contexts.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.customReduce = function (callback, initial) {
    const arr = this;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (initial === undefined && i === 0) {
            initial = arr[0];
            continue;
        }
        initial = callback(initial, arr[i], i);
    }
    return initial;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and place `}` in code blocks, it is currently outisde.

Comment: Adding more details will be helpful, '}' is going outside the block. Also add how your invoking the function ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [1,2,2,4];

 Array.prototype.handReducer = function(cb,value) {
    this.forEach(ele => value = cb(ele,value))
    console.log(value)//9
    return value;
}
const cb = (arr,value) => arr + value;
const new_arr = arr.handReducer(cb,0)
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32415796)

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = [10, 21, 13, 56];

function add(a, b) { return a + b }

Array.prototype.reduce2 = function(fn, start){
  var result = start !== undefined ? start : this[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < this.length; i++) {
    result = fn(result, this[i]);
  }
  return result;
};
console.log(a.reduce(add), a.reduce2(add))
```